# Laravel needs to display only the date not the time using the Carbon class

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

Currently, I am using

> Carbon::now()

It Displays the date with the time

> 2015-03-10 23:23:46

But I only need a date

**2015-03-10**

Comment: did you do it? get only date without 00:00:00. if u did can u post how?

Comment: @SuyeshBhatta Yes. check the answer below by Tjkoopa which is $dt = Carbon::now();
echo $dt->toDateString();

Answer (score 141, accepted):

http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting

```
$dt = Carbon::now();
echo $dt->toDateString(); // Equivalent: echo $dt->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 28):

Simply use this

```
Carbon::today()->toDateString()
```

Answer (score 20):

Get Today's Date in Y-m-d formta as given below,

```
$dt = Carbon::today()->toDateString(); // Use today to display only date
```

if you have used `$dt = Carbon::today()` only, it will return the timestamp also.

Answer (score 14):

This solution will work for you.

```
<td>
    {{$message->created_at->todatestring()}}
</td>
```

Answer (score 10):

This is correctly:

```
$date = Carbon::now();
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use this,

```
echo Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H', '1975-05-21 22')->toDateTimeString();
 // 1975-05-21 22:00:00
```

Example,

```
{{ $post->created_at->toDayDateTimeString()}}
```

[Carbon Docs Source Link](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Comment: output  like this
| Mon, Sep 11, 2017 2:13 PM |

Comment: yup sorry same like above comment, this will not remove the time but rather change the whole out to Mon, Sep 11, 2017 2:13 PM etc

Answer (score 3):

This is very important when you have a critical case for checking due date. Here what you can simply use in your case.

```
Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d')
```

Answer (score 3):

The [now](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-now) helper function creates a new Illuminate\Support\Carbon instance for the current time.

```
// for the current date
Carbon::now() 

// OR 
now()

# output
# 2021-07-02 00:00:00

// OR
Carbon::now()->toDateString() 

// OR 
now()->toDateString()

# output
# 2021-07-02
```

Answer (score 0):

If date time store in database in 2021-07-02 00:00:00 and only want to get time 00:00:00.
It change the 00:00:00 to 05:30:00 in 12-hours format and 12:00:00 in 24-hours format

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).