# How to convert a carbon into string, to take the date only?

Tags: php, laravel, collections, php-carbon

i have an collection like this

```
0 => array:4 [
  "so" => "SO-1"
  "product_name" => "EXTREME FORTE - BP"
  "created_at" => Carbon @1527481346 {#628
    date: 2018-05-28 04:22:26.0 UTC (+00:00)
  }
  "id" => "5b0b84027475aa1508002623"
]
```

how to take the "2018-05-28" only?
can somebody help me to fix this problem? thank's anyway

Comment: You can convert it with `->toDateString()`

Comment: i've try this before make this thread and it cant solve this issue..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel need to display only date not time using the carbon class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28962541/laravel-need-to-display-only-date-not-time-using-the-carbon-class)

Comment: Carbon string formatting [doc](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting) on how a carbon object can be read as a string in different formats.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
$collection_item->created_at->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Just to add to it - you can find some common formatting methods here https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting

Answer (score 25):

i prefere this

```
$model_item->created_at->toDateString();
```

since all date fields that located in `protected $dates array` in the modal is type of `\Carbon\Carbon`.

so the above code could apply to any date field as long as you declared it as date in `$dates array` in the modal
as follow

```
// this includes created_at and updated_at by default so no need to add it 
protected $dates = ['approved', 'seen_at'];
```

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to add automatic casting to your model, for example :

```
protected $casts = [
    'created_at' => 'date:Y-m-d',
    'updated_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:00',
];
```

Remark : your mileage may vary depending on your Laravel version

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#date-serialization

Answer (score 1):

```
 $carbon = Carbon::parse();

 echo (string)$carbon;
 // 2022-04-13 00:00:00

 $carbon->settings(['toStringFormat' => 'Y-m-d']);

 echo (string)$carbon;
 // 2022-04-13
```